# How to include a HTML file in a PHP file?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to call an HTML file in a php file but cant really get any right answer.

I have tried:

```
<?php require/include('filename');>
```

as well as

```
readfile('filename');
```

Doesn't work. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)?

Comment: What you mean by `call an HTML file in a php file` ? Open it? Or Read the content of HTML file?

Comment: Its solved, i just used<?php require/include('filename.php');>

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get the html content inside a php file, you can change your .html file extension to .php and use include() or require().

Example, if you have a file named headings.html, rename it to headings.php and then use:

```
require('headings.php');
```

While require() will produce a fatal error if the file is not found, include() will only produce a warning.